# Which menu does the app be installed in?

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, lxde

I downloaded an application "sendanywhere_latest_amd64.deb" and installed it with dpkg:

```
sudo  dpkg -i  sendanywhere_latest_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package sendanywhere.
(Reading database ... 450701 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack sendanywhere_latest_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sendanywhere (22.6.13-1237) ...
Setting up sendanywhere (22.6.13-1237) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.48) ...
```

There are so many menu in my desktop:

[image: menu on my desktop]

It take me time to search one by one in "Accessories  Debian Education Graphics Internet Office Other Programming Sound&Video  'System Tools' ",how can know quickly which menu does the app be installed in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the package is installed, then look for desktop files with `dpkg -L`:

```
$ dpkg -L gnome-calculator | grep desktop
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop
```

Now we know where the desktop file is stored, let's look at it.  There's a lot in that file, but we are only interested in the "Categories" field:

```
$ grep Categories /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop 
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Calculator;
```

This tells us that `gnome-calculator` is available in the *GNOME*, *GTK*, *Utility*, and/or *Calculator* menus.  Anything with `Categories=Utility` appears in the "Utilities" menu.

---

Here's another example with `meld`:

```
$ grep Categories $(dpkg -L meld | grep desktop)
Categories=GTK;Development;
```

It's in the "Development" menu which appears on my system as "Programming"

---

One more example with `gnome-chess`:

```
$ grep Categories $(dpkg -L gnome-chess | grep desktop)
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Game;BoardGame;
```

This one can be found in the "Games" menu.

---

The menus themselves and the mapping of categories to menus are defined in `*.menu` files defined by the [Desktop Menu Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/menu-spec/).

For me (on gnome) I am looking in `/etc/xdg/menus/gnome-applications.menu` which contains stuff like this:

```
<Menu>
  <Name>Applications</Name>
  <Menu>
    <Name>Games</Name>
    <Include>
      <Category>Game</Category>
    </Include>
  </Menu>
</Menu>
```

That says in the "Applications" menu there is a "Games" sub-menu which includes any desktop files with `Category=Game` in it.

---

> how can know quickly

I suppose this wasn't a quick answer.  If you want to quickly search sub-menus, you'll need to look at what's available in your IDE.  As I mentioned, I'm using gnome, which lets me press WIN to open the lens, and then simply type to search.

Comment: Thanks a lot for having posted your answer at the precise moment I was starting mine :-) Upvoting is much more energie**s** efficient… ;-)

Comment: I also hate it when I get ninja'd